# How to use MongoDBs aggregate `$lookup` as `findOne()`

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So as you all know, `find()` returns an array of results, with `findOne()` returning just a simply object.

With Angular, this makes a huge difference. Instead of going `{{myresult[0].name}}`, I can simply just write `{{myresult.name}}`.

I have found that the `$lookup` method in the aggregate pipeline returns an array of results instead of just a single object.

For example, I have two colletions:

**`users` collection:**

```
[{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "country": 123
}, {
  "firstName": "Luke",
  "lastName": "Jones",
  "country": 321
}]
```

**`countries` collection:**

```
[{
  "name": "Australia",
  "code": "AU",
  "_id": 123
}, {
  "name": "New Zealand",
  "code": "NZ",
  "_id": 321
}]
```

**My aggregate `$lookup`:**

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    "fullName": {
      $concat: ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]
    },
    "country": "$country"
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "countries",
    localField: "country",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "country"
  }
}])
```

**The results from the query:**

```
[{
  "fullName": "John Smith",
  "country": [{
    "name": "Australia",
    "code": "AU",
    "_id": 123
  }]
}, {
 "fullName": "Luke Jones",
 "country": [{
   "name": "New Zealand",
   "code": "NZ",
   "_id": 321
 }]
}]
```

As you can see by the above results, each `country` is an array instead of a single object like `"country": {....}`.

How can I have my `$lookup` return a single object instead of an array since it will only ever match a single document?

Comment: I also feel this should be handled from their end. If there is just one match, it should return an object and not an array with a single object.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to add another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to your pipeline and use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return the single element in the array.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {   "$project": {     
            "fullName": {       
                "$concat": [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]     
            },
            "country": "$country"   
        }}, 
        { "$lookup": {     
                "from": "countries",     
                "localField": "country",     
                "foreignField": "_id",     
                "as": "countryInfo"   
        }}, 
        { "$project": { 
            "fullName": 1, 
            "country": 1, 
            "countryInfo": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$countryInfo", 0 ] } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

Comment: Now you can also use `$unwind` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: As a 2¢ add-on late in the game, I'm a fan of pairings of `$lookup` followed by `$unwind`.  Part of my brain likes to think that that combination can be optimized server-side in a similar way to `$limit` and `$sort` combining (where the `sort` operation only tracks `limit` records).

Comment: And if you want to control which fields are included in elements selected using `$arrayElemAt` – without doing another `$project` stage – you can use `$let`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650846/483520

Comment: what about using $set instead of $project ?

Comment: Instead of `$arrayElemAt`, you can also use the [`$first` array operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element) (introduced in version 4.4): `{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$countryInfo", 0 ] } ` becomes `{ "$first": "$countryInfo" }`

Comment: @JonasWanke you can even do better by running a pipeline in the `$lookup` stage in version >= 5.0

Answer (score 38):

You can also use `"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays"`

Like so:

```
 db.users.aggregate(
        [
            {   "$project": {     
                "fullName": {       
                    "$concat": [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]     
                },
                "country": "$country"   
            }}, 
            { "$lookup": {     
                    "from": "countries",     
                    "localField": "country",     
                    "foreignField": "_id",     
                    "as": "countryInfo"   
            }}, 
            {"$unwind": {
                    "path": "$countryInfo",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
                }
            },
        ]
    )
```

Comment: { $unwind: { path: '$countryInfo' } } is enough.

Comment: And for ease of use, why not create view and reference this just as a normal collection (with a few restrictions) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/

Comment: { $unwind: '$countryInfo'  } is also enough

Comment: @benipsen if you don't have a 1-1 relation, will omitting `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` filter out identities without `countryInfo` or will `countryInfo` be undefined?

Comment: @CervEd thanks for raising this possible issue. I tested, and indeed it seems an issue -- $unwind in this case is effectively a full-join and will remove the entire entry if the array is empty. So, `"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true` is necessary.

Comment: Also, if your relation is 1-n, unwind may give unexpected results.

Answer (score 16):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'countries',
            localField: 'country',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'country'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$country'
    }
]).pretty()
```

You can use this mongo query for getting the country object

Answer (score 10):

When you don't want to repeat all fields in project, just overwrite the field in question with $addFields:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {   "$project": {     
        "fullName": {       
            "$concat": [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]     
        },
        "country": "$country"   
    }}, 
    { "$lookup": {     
        "from": "countries",     
        "localField": "country",     
        "foreignField": "_id",     
        "as": "countryInfo"   
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "countryInfo": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [ "$countryInfo", 0 ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: This is the solution I came with. `$project` makes the code less maintainable when more fields are added to the collection. If you are doing `$unwind`, make sure `"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true`. But this returns unexpected results if multiple matches found. This answer should work in all cases for `findOne` relation

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach would be to add another step to the pipeline:

```
...,
{
  $addFields : {
    $country: { $first: '$country' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use ***$project*** or ***$addFields***.

Where we can use ***$project*** is, if you know what are all the fields you need further, in that case you can go with ***$project***.

example:

```
{ 
    "$project": { 
        "fullName": 1, 
        "country": 1, 
        "countryInfo": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$countryInfo", 0 ] } 
    }
}
```

Where we can use ***$addFields*** is, if you are not sure about the remaining fields and you just want to modify the specific lookup field, in that case we can go with ***$addFields***.

example.

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "countryInfo": {
            "$arrayElemAt": ["$countryInfo", 0]
        }
    }
}
```