# How to use $arrayElemAt and remove fields from that element in MongoDB $projection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 'jobs' and 'users' collection. Every user can create a job for given 'jobCategoryId', that job is then saved in 'jobs' collection and contains 'userId' of it's creator and 'jobCategoryId'.

I'm trying to combine these 2 collections so when I fetch jobs, I'll have 'user' field with all user data instead of 'userId' field for that job. This is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
Job.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    jobCategoryId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jobCategoryId)
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'userId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'user'
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    description: 1,
    title: 1,
    user: { $arrayElemAt: ['$user', 0] }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    title: 1,
    description: 1,
    'user.name': '$user.name'
  }
}])
```

This returns following:

```
[{
  _id: 'some id',
  title: 'title',
  description: 'description',
  user: {
    name: 'Mike'
  }
}]
```

result is correct but I'm really interested if there is any other way to keep only some fields from user object directly while using $arrayElemAt or am I doomed to use 2 projections in pipeline?
Could anyone help me with this little problem? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is from the syntax of [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

> The  expression can be any valid expression as long as it
>   resolves to an array.

Which means you can construct your array elements however you want. In your case you want only the name. So this should work:

```
[{
  $match: {
    jobCategoryId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jobCategoryId)
  }
}, {  
  $lookup: {  
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'userId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'user'
  }
}, {  
  $project: {  
    _id: 1,
    description: 1,
    title: 1,
    user: {  
      name: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$user.name", 0]
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

**Follow up UPDATE**:
it was asked how to additional properties on top of `name` . Here is the project:

```
{  
  $project: {  
    _id: 1,
    description: 1,
    title: 1,
    user: {  
      name: {  
        $arrayElemAt: ["$user.name", 0]
      },
      email: {  
        $arrayElemAt: ["$user.email", 0]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Second follow up** as Drag0 asked in the comments: If the above isn't good enough because the results generate a user:[] array of size 1 instead of an object user:{} the following can be used.

```
{  
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    description: 1,
    title: 1,
    user: {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          firstUser: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0]
          }
        },
        in: {
          name: "$$firstUser.name",
          email: "$$firstUser.email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if user object has more fields like email? Could I just add it like this:  $project:{  
         _id:1,
         description:1,
         title:1,
         "user.name":  {$arrayElemAt:["$user.name",0]},
          "user.email": {$arrayElemAt:["$user.email",0]},
         }
      }

Comment: That should work. But I also updated the answer to reflect a slightly different way of doing this.

Comment: This solution actually returns user not as an object, but as an array with size 1. So there is user: [{name: "name", email: "email"}]. Do you have any idea how could I solve this one? I could do it on frontend but I think it would be better to do it on backend.

Comment: Yes, you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/). That should do the job for you. Basically it creates a temporary variable for you to use.

Comment: Thank you Amin, I appreciate your help a lot.